# What are the advantages/disadvantages of using mdf vs sql db server

Tags: sql-server, comparison, sql-server-express

What is the difference between using SQL Express .mdf file and an actual SQL Server DB? Why wouldn't I use .mdf file for everything? Is there a size or performance limitation that would prompt me to use SQL Server DB? I currently use actual SQL Server DB's for every project I work on so I am just curious to know if an .mdf file might be more cost-effective.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Express runs only one scheduler, so can use basically only one processor. It imposes  a hard limit of 4GB on database size. It won't use more than 1 GB of RAM. And many features are license restricted, like certain replication scenarios. [See here a full comparisson](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compare-features.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Express has features deliberately removed to make it less useful.  For instance, databases are limited to 4 GB in size, and it can only use 1 GB of RAM.  I recommend you look into FOSS databases like [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) and [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), which don't limit you like this.